# Неясный стек исключений в приложении javaFx

Tags: java, json, javafx

Коллеги, добрый день!
Вот такой стек исключения выдается при запуске собранного мавеном джарника моего приложения:

```
SEVERE: null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
        at ru.vkf.VkApp.App.start(App.java:27)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161 (LauncherImpl.java:863)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

То же самое выдается при сборке артифакта в  intellij Idea

При непосредственном запуске с помощью красивой зеленой стрелочки в идее - все работает отлично

Проявляться начало когда добавил в приложение

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
  <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Аналогичная история с другими json-парсерами

Вот код Main класса

```
package ru.vkf.VkApp;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(App.class, (java.lang.String[])null);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(App.class.getResource("fxml/hello.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setTitle("VkFriend");
            primaryStage.setResizable(false);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Cпасибо за помощь!

Comment: покажите структуру проекта, где App, где fxml. И какая версия java?

Comment: Структура проекта:
https://pastenow.ru/2ba85f034344f2c0ce43101a987dc435

jdk - 8u181

Answer (score 1):

`App.class.getResource("fxml/hello.fxml")` делает следующее:
1. Находит относительный путь до App = `ru.unic.VkApp`
2. Идет по такому же пути в ресурсах = `ru/unic/VkApp/`
3. добавляет к пути указанный в кавычках параметр = `ru/unic/VkApp/fxml/hello.fxml`
4. Не находит по этому пути искомый файл

Решение:
а. Создайте в ресурсах структуру которую программа ищет.
б. Используйте путь относительно корня ресурсов `/fxml/hello.fxml`

Я обычно делаю по пути а.

Comment: Спасибо!
Сделал по пути б, тк не совсем понял, какая структура требуется в способе а

если имелось в виду в директории resources создать путь ru/unic/VkApp/fxml/ и переместить туда hello.fxml - так тоже пробовал

Теперь при запуске выдает следующее:

https://pastebin.com/08qdgC66

Comment: @МаксимФролов [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Возникающая у вас теперь ошибка - это уже другая проблема, связанная с управлением зависимостями, задайте для неё отдельный вопрос.